# Select same value multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to select a value multiple times.

I've tried using the following queries:
$id_nums = 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2

```
   SELECT Name FROM Events WHERE ID IN ($id_nums)
```

The following query did the job although not fully, as IN is removing "duplicates" so the result returned me one row with ID of 1 and 1 row with ID of 2.

My 2nd attempt, was done using this query:
$id_nums = (1), (1), (1), (2) , (2)

```
SELECT Name FROM Events EVNT RIGHT JOIN (SELECT Name FROM (VALUES $id_nums  )AS X(a)) AS test ON EVNT.Name = test.a;
```

Although that didn't work too, as the syntax is wrong. I can't see the error I made there.

The actual result I am expecting would be that if I select "rows", I would see actually the rows selected. Such as if $id_nums = 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2
then I would get  4 rows of data with ID =1, and 3 rows of data with ID = 2

Comment: Are your IDs not unique/auto incrementing? I'd cut the PHP out of this and get it working as a mysql query first.

Comment: show us the dataset of your Events table. Your Id may be unique

Comment: My IDs are unique, and they are all incremented. The thing is that I want to fetch data equal to the number of IDs provided, not just "2 rows" if the query is "1, 1, 1" then 3 identical rows need to be fetched   >> https://imgur.com/a/IBGFcSW

Comment: nope `IN` doen't work like that

Comment: You are joining other tables? Please provide sample data and table structure.

Comment: That's how my "ID" is created `  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`

Comment: @user3783243 That other table is temp table from IDs provided, that's what I thought could be a solution to my issue by creating a temp table and just using this to filter it through although that didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate a list of numbers and use `left join` (or `right join`, but I much prefer `left join`.  In MySQL, you do this using `select` and `union all`:

```
select e.name
from (select 1 as id union all
      select 1 as id union all
      select 1 as id union all
      select 1 as id union all
      select 2 as id union all
      select 2 as id union all
      select 2 as id
     ) i left join
     events e
     on e.id = i.id;
```

Comment: topicstarter If you also want to fix the order you can/need to add `ORDER BY FIELD(e.id, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like with `UNION ALL` clause

```
SELECT Name FROM Events WHERE ID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT Name FROM Events WHERE ID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT Name FROM Events WHERE ID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT Name FROM Events WHERE ID=1
UNION ALL
SELECT Name FROM Events WHERE ID=2
UNION ALL
SELECT Name FROM Events WHERE ID=2
```